# Where can I find Xcodes own logs?

Tags: xcode, macos

Where can I find `Xcode`s own logs in Mac? I can see many logs from `Console` app but I want to filter logs for only `Xcode` app. How can I do so?

Comment: There's a filter text field in the toolbar.

Comment: @KenThomases When I filter with `Any: Xcode` that shows empty. Is there any separate file to look for Xcode logs?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to find logged from Xcode? In any case, when you launch Console, it only shows logs from that point in time, forward. It doesn't load past logs. Did you do anything in Xcode **after** you launched Console?

Comment: @ken lets say when I run ui operations i.e. start build from xcode ui there must be some internal commands executed i.e. xcodebuild. I want to see those logs what commands are actually being run in background for ui option selection.

Comment: Well, the build logs (shown within Xcode) include the compilation commands. I doubt that Xcode runs an external command to manage the build itself. I think it just does that in-process. (Probably, both Xcode and `xcodebuild` use a common private framework as a build engine.) You can also probably use a DTrace tool such as `execsnoop` to see what Xcode is doing, although you may have to disable (parts of) System Integrity Protection to use DTrace.